# How to add a keystore to an Eclipse project

Tags: java, ajax, eclipse, ssl

I've asked a similar question not too long ago, but I feel like I didn't ask it correctly.  I've been tasked with creating a project that consumes a web service.  This web service requires a certificate to send ajax calls to.  My team member sent me a jks file that contains the relevant cert, but I'm unsure on how to actually add it to my eclipse project, and I can't find any information through searches.

How do I add the keystore to my project so that I have the necessary PKC and AC to make AJAX calls?

Comment: Are you using tomcat?

Comment: @MiiinimalLogic yeah, I have a tomcat 7 server to host my code for now.

Answer (score 0):

The keystore (with certificate) should be included/assigned in your Tomcat instance.  Use the following link to do so:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: If you already have the cert imported to the keystore, then you can skip down to the Edit Configuration section.